# Can someone tell me how to call a lua function?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am such a noob and I need to know how to call a function in lua I will give example function.

```
local function exampleHD(event)
--Function details and such
end
```

How would I call this for "local obj = display.newImageRect( "Random.jpg" , 90, 60 )"

Comment: This question presents lack of fundamental understanding of the language. Before trying to program anything, you should spend some time learning the language you're trying to write in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call a function by using its name (to be more precise, its value stored in a variable with that name) with an argument list in parentheses (there are several forms that allows you to skip parentheses). See [Function Calls](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8) in the Lua Manual for details.

In your case you can call `exampleHD` as `exampleHD(event)`. In the second snippet you shown, it's a proper call of the function stored in `display.newImageRect` element with three parameters.